# Synchronization of data between web & C#

Tags: c#, mysql, synchronization, webserver

I have created a web system to display a timetable of teachers.

Teachers have a desktop application (used C#) in their laptops with the same system as web system.

THE CASE IS;
- When the teachers connect to Internet they can fetch the timetables allocated for them. 
- Teachers are allowed edit the timetable using their desktop application. 
- They must have the ability to sync it to the web system when Internet connection is there.

PROBLEMS:
- I have no idea about how to sync these updated data to the online database.
- How can I temporarily store the fetched , and (or) edited data in the desktop application without creating a temporary database? 
- Is there any technology/ plugin to do this task easily?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, the best option would be to have a local store that can store the application data and sync up with the server whenever the internet connection is working.

The mode would be a database, however, a secure file system also sounds fine.

There is a great deal of thought process involved with using the offline sync model. There should be a conflict check with the server before any data gets overridden to the db. Also,  the client app should not loose data between restarts.

I would suggest that you decide on the right approach to sync data, prepare and review the process and consider Various algorithm's for the sync. In case of any specific questions, please post your questions here.

Comment: Thank you for the instruction. I think XML file gives the solution.